# Suggestion: Review Queue for Question from Banned Users

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, asking-questions, post-ban, question-quality

I have a suggestion to allow users to positively get back into contributing to the SO community and I searched google to no avail so I'm hoping this isn't a duplicate.

What if users were allowed to post a question that first went to a "review queue" if there account was banned from asking questions. There could be algorithms/rules on how often. Something like 1 question after a month and if it's not accepted then 2 months or something along those lines. I would leave that to the SO Dev's to pin down the details.

It can be quite hard on this site to get out of a ban with the amount of bad questions and also active users answering the good questions before newer users can figure it out/write it up.

What is the community’s thoughts on this?

Comment: Soooooo...users who have demonstrated that they shouldn't have the ability to post because it creates more work for curators, should make more work for curators because they really need to ask questions?

Comment: so, kinda like the one free question you get every 6 months? My 2 cents: considering the warnings, the amount of help available for question writing, once someone is banned, I don't think providing methods for them to be unbanned that results in more work for **others** make sense. Editing your question bumps them to the top of the active questions queue.... + you have the free question every 6 months. That seems enough to me, and it puts the onus in the right place.

Comment: @fbueckert You don't have to curate, it should be something you do out of passion. Patrice, I forgot about the 6 months thing, that is similar to what I am describing. While you can edit your questions, I feel that is a lot harder then asking a new good question. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @Free it is indeed harder... but once someone is banned, I personally don't think we should make it easier to get out of ban, at the expense of our curators..... basically: yes it's hard.... but.... maybe it should be.

Comment: Yes, we do it out of passion. And that means those that have proven they shouldn't be allowed to post, shouldn't be draining more of that passion than they already have.  Getting into the question ban isn't easy; you're given multiple warnings.  Unfortunately, most users, as far as I can tell, don't appreciate those warnings and ignore them.  So...not sure what we should tell them, other than what we already have.

Comment: I have no objections to such a queue - new accounts could look at the queue and see many examples of the kinds of questions that SO finds unfit for purpose.   Obviously, the queue must be read-only,  no votes or answers, else it would be misused immediate.

Comment: @MartinJames There's not exactly a shortage of bad questions to serve as examples.  If you want to make a readonly queue of "bad examples" to show people who want to know what's bad then just make that readonly queue of very low scoring closed questions we already have.  No need to request more for the purpose.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Why should we create *additional* work for reviewers? They've already had to review multiple questions posted by the user who is question-banned, and that user has already had multiple warnings regarding the quality of their questions. [Question bans don't just come out of nowhere](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

Also, this is sort of already implemented. Question-banned users have the ability to ask *one* question every six months. This is somewhat like a rate limit. No one is ever actually "banned", only severely rate-limited: until you demonstrate that you have the ability to ask questions that meet our quality standards, you are limited to asking one question every six months. It is possible for a person to use this opportunity to ask a high-quality question that gets several upvotes, demonstrating that they've learned how to ask good questions, and thus digging themselves out of the question "ban". If not, and their question is poorly received by the community, they'll only dig themselves further into the hole, but because it's not actually a ban, they'll still have the chance to try again with another question in six months.